# Transform nested arrays in Ruby to group items with the same id

Tags: ruby, arrays, transformation

I have an array:

```
[[1,"Location1"],[1,"Location2"],[1,"Location3"],[2,"Location4"],[2,"Location5"],[2,"Location6"]]
```

How can I map this array so that I get:

```
[[1,["Location1", "Location2", "Location3"]],[2,["Location4", "Location5", "Location6"]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as below :-

```
array = [[1,"Location1"],[1,"Location2"],[1,"Location3"],[2,"Location4"],[2,"Location5"],[2,"Location6"]]
array.group_by(&:first).map { |k, v_ary| [k, v_ary.map(&:last)] }
# => [[1, ["Location1", "Location2", "Location3"]], [2, ["Location4", "Location5", "Location6"]]]
```

## or

```
array.each_with_object(Hash.new { |hsh, key| hsh[key] = [] }) { |(f,l), h| h[f] << l }.to_a
# => [[1, ["Location1", "Location2", "Location3"]], [2, ["Location4", "Location5", "Location6"]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[1,"Location1"],[1,"Location2"],[1,"Location3"],[2,"Location4"],[2,"Location5"],[2,"Location6"]].each_with_object({}) do |element, array|
  array[element[0]] ||= []
  array[element[0]].push(array[element[1]])
end.to_a
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is more or less going to be a loop walker that creates a new array, so lets make that a function

```
def reOrgArr(arr)
  i = 0
  j = [[]]
  loop do
    group = arr[i]
    name = group[1]
    newgroup = group[0]
    j[newgroup].push(name)
    i += 1
    if i > arr.len break  # this will cause execution to exit the loop
  end
  return j
end

arr = [[1,"Location1"],[1,"Location2"],[1,"Location3"],[2,"Location4"],[2,"Location5"],[2,"Location6"]]
 newArr = reOrgArr(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with (note that it mutates original items in collection):

```rb
arr.group_by(&:shift).transform_values(&:flatten).to_a
```

Step by step explanation:

- given `arr`

```rb
[[1,"Location1"],[1,"Location2"],[1,"Location3"],[2,"Location4"],[2,"Location5"],[2,"Location6"]]
```

- `.group_by(&:shift)` group by first element, removing it from every item (mutates items in collection)

```rb
{1=>[["Location1"], ["Location2"], ["Location3"]], 2=>[["Location4"], ["Location5"], ["Location6"]]}
```

- `.transform_values(&:flatten)` unnest array of arrays

```rb
{1=>["Location1", "Location2", "Location3"], 2=>["Location4", "Location5", "Location6"]}
```

- `.to_a` convert Hash to Array

```rb
[[1, ["Location1", "Location2", "Location3"]], [2, ["Location4", "Location5", "Location6"]]]
```